# How to reload the page on back button click in any browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have created the HTML page for example page1.html with some setting onclick invoke page2.html

On Click Back button the page1 is getting loaded will all previous data. I want complete reload of page and donot want to remeber any setting.

Regards,
Dev

Answer (score 2):

Set the following headers:

```
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache
expires: 0
```

Comment: I have tried this and doesn't refresh the page when clicking the back button

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is to expire page1 - for example

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

in the head of that page

Comment: Hmm interesting comment on using window.name to check that the page has been visited. You could use a timestamp there too.
SECOND code comment: http://dev.opera.com/forums/topic/224464

Comment: I tired but it is not working...........
<?php 
include("CheckProcessingData.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">

Comment: meta http-equiv tags don't work for certain headers. For ones that don't work, you must use true headers (e.g. through header() in PHP)

Comment: I have tried this and doesn't refresh the page when clicking the back button

Comment: What browser, what platform, what cache settings?